# Bing Maps API - Remove Pins

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I've got a select box which allows the user to toggle between various lists which populate a bing map with points.

However when they select a different location from the list I need to remove the old pins before plotting the new ones.

Any ideas, the API docs don't seem to cover it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove a single pushpin (or any other kind of entity) from the map, you need to call the remove() method of the entitycollection that contains the pin: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427616.aspx.
Or, if you want to reference the entity by index, use removeAt() instead.

To clear all entities from a collection, call the clear() method instead.

Answer (score 5):

Just to make things clear. Cause it to me a while to figure it out.

Create a push pin in JavaScipt:

```js
var thisPin;
var location new Microsoft.Maps.Location(YourLatitude, Your.longitude);


thisPin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location, {
    icon: 'path to image',
    anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(YourOffsetX, YourOffsetY)
});
map.entities.push(thisPin);
```

To remove the pin, you must still have the pointer thisPin pointing to that specific pin.

```
map.entities.remove(thisPin);
```

This method is not well documented in the samples.

Answer (score 1):

the deleteAllShapes() in the javascript will do this, i am working on the same thing now and it works,